# Web Colors - Light Grays on PC not showing

Tags: colors

I could be completely off but just wanted to see if there was anything on this subject:

I'm developing a site at the moment that includes a few DIVs that use different shades of really light greys for background and border colors. On both my Mac (laptop and desktop) the colors can be seen quite easily. However, on PC (both Firefox and IE) the colors are not there at all.

The current colors I have are `#E9E9E9` and `#E1E1E1`.

The weird thing is when I change the colors to something darker like `#CCCCCC` the color is easily seen on PCs and I would assume I could put up a few more shades lighter. But when I move it to the next color like `#DDDDDD` the color is completely gone.

Just on a limb but is there any weird thing like PC's not rendering certain color codes or am I just trying to make something out of nothing here?

Comment: Could you please provide a link/sample to the page/site so people could see if it's your computer, or IE + Firefox in general?

Comment: Yeah I can put one up in a bit.. have to remove client info since it can't be released yet!

Comment: There were the "web" colors, back in the old "everyone has 256 color desktops" days, where you were only supposed to use rgb triplets where the components were multiples of 3. But those are thankfully long gone.

Answer (score 2):

I've been in the exact situation and I had a hard time designing UIs because of this issue.

I'm on **Ubuntu 18.04 and Chrome**, either of which **is not the problem**.
This issue resides in the monitor settings, in my case I'm using a **Samsung Monitor**.

I've solved my issue by doing the following:

- Reveal your Monitor Settings (via some button in your monitor).
- Navigate to Menu, and then go to Picture.
- Scroll down to reveal the other settings down below.
- Set **HDMI Black Level** to *Normal*

Instantaneously you'll see your black colors improved.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any problem with a PC displaying those colors.  It could be a problem with your PC's video settings or your monitor.  Have you tried it with multiple PCs and monitors?

Comment: No I haven't.. going to soon though. I was just confused since it displayed #CCC quite clear with definitely room for a few shades to lighten up..

Comment: @Jeff: Maybe on one of your Macs create an image with a gradient from white to black.  Then, try to display the image on your PC.  I'd guess it will show up as bars of solid color rather than a smooth gradient.  Right click on your desktop and look for a place to change your color settings.  If everything checks out then try going through your monitor's settings.

Comment: I did your test and noticed that just that certain area, from shades of lighter grays to white, isn't a smooth transition. It pretty much skips and a few shades and just goes white..

Comment: @Jeff: Interesting... maybe it could still be due to some monitor setting, or else a malfunction.  In regard to your original question though, this is not a common feature of PCs - they should handle all colors just as well as your Macs do :)